# How to tap two points with InjectTouchInput

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, touch, touch-event

I want to tap two points (`c[0]` and `c[1]`) with `InjectTouchInput()`, but only `c[1]` is tapped, `c[0]` is not tapped.

Is there something wrong?

`InjectTouchInput()` is a API to emulate touch events.

https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-injecttouchinput

It can be called by C#.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/TCD.System.TouchInjection/

```cs
using System;
using TCD.System.TouchInjection;
using static TCD.System.TouchInjection.TouchInjector;


// https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-injecttouchinput?redirectedfrom=MSDN

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        private static PointerTouchInfo createPointer(uint id)
        {
            var pointer = new PointerTouchInfo();
            //We can add different additional touch data 
            pointer.TouchMasks = TouchMask.PRESSURE;
            pointer.Pressure = 100;


            //Pointer ID is for gesture tracking 
            pointer.PointerInfo.PointerId = id;
            pointer.PointerInfo.pointerType = PointerInputType.TOUCH;

            return pointer;
        }
        private static void tap(int x, int y)
        {
            var c = new[] { createPointer(1), createPointer(2) };

            // Touch contact down
            c[0].PointerInfo.PtPixelLocation.X = x;
            c[0].PointerInfo.PtPixelLocation.Y = y;
            c[0].PointerInfo.PointerFlags = PointerFlags.INRANGE | PointerFlags.INCONTACT | PointerFlags.DOWN;
            c[1].PointerInfo.PtPixelLocation.X = x+110;
            c[1].PointerInfo.PtPixelLocation.Y = y;
            c[1].PointerInfo.PointerFlags = PointerFlags.INRANGE | PointerFlags.INCONTACT | PointerFlags.DOWN;
            InjectTouchInput(2, c);

            // Touch contact up and transition to hover
            c[0].PointerInfo.PointerFlags = PointerFlags.INRANGE | PointerFlags.UP;
            c[1].PointerInfo.PointerFlags = PointerFlags.INRANGE | PointerFlags.UP;
            InjectTouchInput(2, c);

        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (InitializeTouchInjection())
            {
                tap(350, 650);
            } else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Hello Tap Emulation!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Two-finger touch input usually gets translated, commonly into what corresponds to a right-click. Could this be interfering?

Comment: Two touch events are not translated into a right-click. two touch-effect are shown on c[0] point and c[1] point. (but tapped only c[1]). Parhaps, touch-down emulate is OK, but touch-up emulate is mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Browser Touch Test

[Multitouch Test](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/multitouch.html)

[Touch events - Example - code sample](https://mdn.mozillademos.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events$samples/Example?revision=1560235)

[Touch events - Web API | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Touch_events)

```
color for touch with identifier 1 = #100
touchend
color for touch with identifier 0 = #000
touchend
touchstart:0.
color for touch with identifier 1 = #100
touchstart:0...
touchstart.
touchstart:0.
color for touch with identifier 0 = #000
touchstart:0...
touchstart.
initialized.
```

Browser Test works fine.
It may not be a code issue, but an application...

Comment: You can [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) your own answer.